# Is there a way to minify all my js/css files while rendering to the browser but not while editing it in the IDE?

Tags: javascript, npm, minify, uglifyjs

My js file has a lot of comments and spaces which increases its size and slows down the website. So I am looking for a way to minify all that when I start the server but I should be able to edit it with my original file. Basically the browser sees the minified version when we 'view page source' but I should be able to see the commented version in my IDE. Is there any npm package or any way we can do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done with a build tool such as [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (there are many others).

Parcel is maybe the simplest to setup, because the most important features - including minifying - are built in, or are configured automatically, however it may depend on how you have organized your project. In the best case you just need to [install it](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/)

```
npm install --save-dev parcel
```

and then you can [create a production build](https://parceljs.org/features/production/) with

```
parcel build index.html
```

(if `index.html` is your main file).